# How to get more of the basic Gwent cards?

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I googled for Gwent cards, I could see that everyone is out to get the most powerful and cool cards.

Well I'm actually interested in certain basic cards that show strength in numbers. Nobody should underestimate deck full of Dwarven Skirmishers or Arachas.

So my question is, where can I get more of these cards? Some vendors sell up to 5 random cards and I won some cards from vendors as well. Will their inventory of cards ever restock? Is there other way to get greater amount of basic cards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only a finite amount of Gwent cards exist in the game. They can be obtained by buying them from innkeepers or winning against opponents in a game of Gwent. However, vendors never restock on cards and opponents never award more than 1 card.

For an exhaustive list, detailing how many copies of a card exist and where to find them, you can consult one of the community-created databases such as [gwent-cards.com](http://gwent-cards.com/).

Comment: Let's add complex quests and advanced opponents will give you advanced cards. Common traders, innkeepers and assorted random Gwent players are the best source of basic cards.